# Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment in Angular 6

Tags: typescript, angular6

I'm working on angular 6 app, i have login page & i want to redirect from login to dashboard page. I have added routing in app.component.ts. But it shows an error
"Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'dashbaord' ". Pls let me know where i missed in it.
**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LogingComponent } from './loging/loging.component';
import { SidebarComponent } from './sidebar/sidebar.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LogingComponent,
    SidebarComponent,
    DashboardComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**login.component.ts**

```
import { DashboardComponent } from './../dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-loging',
  templateUrl: './loging.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./loging.component.css']
})
export class LogingComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private router: Router) { }
  public onLoginClick() {
    console.log('Hi');
    this.router.navigate(['./dashbaord']);
}
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

**app.routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { LogingComponent } from './loging/loging.component';
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LogingComponent},
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent}
 ];    
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**dashboard.component.ts**

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A typo in your login ruins your party.

Instead of

```
this.router.navigate(['./dashbaord']);
```

Do...

```
this.router.navigate(['./dashboard']);
```

Comment: @ak.leimery 
It's working but now it shows "Cannot POST /dashboard"

Comment: Could you add the code of your dashboard too, please?

Comment: @ak.leimery pls check, i have updated my question with dashboard code

Comment: I would rebuild the project, creating the project with the Angular CLI from anew. I can't really see what else in your coding would have caused this issue. It still seems modest in size. I did a similar setup with yours and didn't encounter any further problem.

Comment: What you suggest on this, should i reinstall angular cli??

Comment: That would be the most hardcore solution. Do me a favor... open a new project and create simply two components. One the first template you simply write something like "Template One" and on the other "Template two". On Template one, add a button that will route you to "Template" two. No more, no less. E.g. (click)="routeToTemplateTwo()"